# Formatting Text Boxes in a Userform

Tags: vba, excel, textbox, userform

I have a Userform that includes Text Boxes with multiple formats. I have the Initialize as blank ("") and then format them using afterupdate(). This all works fine, my issues come from the possibility of the user miss keying the data the first go around or just clicking aimlessly on there screen. After you input a value it formats it correctly when you move from the text box. But if you reselect the text box then move away again, it clears the value. And if you do this with the text box that is formatted as a percent it actually bugs out with a mismatch error.

Here is a slice of my current code:

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()

   ValueAnalysisTextBox.Value = ""

   CapRateTextBox.Value = ""

End Sub

Private Sub ValueAnalysisTextBox_AfterUpdate()

   ValueAnalysisTextBox.Value = Format(Val(ValueAnalysisTextBox.Value), "$#,###")

End Sub

Private Sub CapRateTextBox_AfterUpdate()

   CapRateTextBox.Value = Format(Val(CapRateTextBox.Value) / 100, "Percent")

End Sub
```

Any thoughts on how to clean this up would be great.

Comment: The formatting should be done during code execution.  If you want the user to see what the end result is going to look like, I recommend using labels instead of textboxes to show the formatted text.

Comment: If you need the formatted text to be in the textbox though, you'll have to introduce a check in the `After_Update` code to see if the textbox value is already in the format necessary and if so, make no changes.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are trying?

```
Private Sub ValueAnalysisTextBox_AfterUpdate()
    Dim amt As Double

    amt = Val(Replace(ValueAnalysisTextBox.Value, "$", ""))

    ValueAnalysisTextBox.Value = Format(amt, "$#,###")
End Sub

Private Sub CapRateTextBox_AfterUpdate()
    Dim Perct As Double

    Perct = Val(Replace(CapRateTextBox.Value, "%", "")) / 100

    CapRateTextBox.Value = Format(Perct, "Percent")
End Sub
```

**Note**: I am not doing any other error handling. For example, user typing "Blah Blah" or pasting something else in the textbox. I am sure you can handle that.

Comment: This I producing the same result for me. If there is already a value in the text box and you enter the text box and exit it again. It clears the original value.

Comment: I tried it and it working just fine for me? Is `,` your decimal separator?

Answer (score 0):

I'd store the underlying values in the `.Tag` property of the TextBox, then use it to change the formatting back and forth in the Enter and Exit events:

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
    ValueAnalysisTextBox.Value = vbNullString
    ValueAnalysisTextBox.Tag = vbNullString
End Sub

Private Sub ValueAnalysisTextBox_Enter()
    ValueAnalysisTextBox.Value = ValueAnalysisTextBox.Tag
End Sub

Private Sub ValueAnalysisTextBox_Exit(ByVal Cancel As MSForms.ReturnBoolean)
    If IsNumeric(ValueAnalysisTextBox.Value) Then
        ValueAnalysisTextBox.Tag = Val(ValueAnalysisTextBox.Value)
        ValueAnalysisTextBox.Value = Format$(ValueAnalysisTextBox.Tag, "$#,###")
    Else
        ValueAnalysisTextBox.Tag = vbNullString
    End If
End Sub
```